# How to investigate why container exit in restart=always mode?

Tags: docker

I have container restarted itself 3 times and still working.
How can I know why it restarted? and how i can see the logs for each time the container has exit?

Comment: see `docker logs` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for the id with:

`docker ps -a`

Let's say you see your container with Exited status, and you can check the logs of that container with

`docker logs your_container_here`

You can also follow the logs by

`docker logs -f your_container_here`

Answer (score 0):

You can check logs of stopped container by container id with docker logs command

sample :

```
docker logs 99e691c271c9
```

and You can get container ids by running

```
docker ps -a (for all containers)

or

docker ps -al (for latest/last stopped container)
```